# Android - MaterialCardView corner radius not showing up in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cardview

I created a cornerRadius card view and my codes work well in activity but the problem now is that the cardview does not show the rounded edges and elevation in fragment but it shows in the design codes and in activity. my codes are shown blow:
raounded_corners.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/text_bg"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green_500"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_session"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/photo_male_7" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raounded_corners,container,false);
        return v;
    }
```

raounded_corners.xml layout cornerRadius showing in activity but not showing in fragment
How to fix this.

In Activity
[image]

in fragment
[image]

Comment: Try Shapeable ImageView instead of card once.

Comment: Did it make any change?

Comment: Just a comment- your CardView is not a perfect circle.
The radius value should be at least half the width/height.
Change it to 55dp

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the imageview circular, I propose this approach.Create the custom view and set it in your xml. It works perfectly. If this helps you, an upvote will be appreciated.

> Create a custom Circular view like shown below. CircleImageView.java

```
        package com.fishpott.fishpott5.Views;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.res.TypedArray;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
        import android.graphics.Canvas;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
        import android.graphics.Matrix;
        import android.graphics.Paint;
        import android.graphics.RectF;
        import android.graphics.Shader;
        import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
        import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
        import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
        import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;
        import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
        import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
        import android.util.AttributeSet;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        import com.fishpott.fishpott5.R;


        public class CircleImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

            private static final ImageView.ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

            private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

            private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
            private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
            private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR = Color.TRANSPARENT;
            private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

            private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
            private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

            private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
            private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
            private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();
            private final Paint mFillPaint = new Paint();

            private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
            private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
            private int mFillColor = DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR;

            private Bitmap mBitmap;
            private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
            private int mBitmapWidth;
            private int mBitmapHeight;

            private float mDrawableRadius;
            private float mBorderRadius;

            private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

            private boolean mReady;
            private boolean mSetupPending;
            private boolean mBorderOverlay;
            private boolean mDisableCircularTransformation;

            public CircleImageView(Context context) {
                super(context);

                init();
            }

            public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                this(context, attrs, 0);
            }

            public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);

                TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

                mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
                mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
                mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);
                mFillColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_fill_color, DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR);

                a.recycle();

                init();
            }

            private void init() {
                super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
                mReady = true;

                if (mSetupPending) {
                    setup();
                    mSetupPending = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public ImageView.ScaleType getScaleType() {
                return SCALE_TYPE;
            }

            @Override
            public void setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType scaleType) {
                if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
                if (adjustViewBounds) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                if (mDisableCircularTransformation) {
                    super.onDraw(canvas);
                    return;
                }

                if (mBitmap == null) {
                    return;
                }

                if (mFillColor != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(mDrawableRect.centerX(), mDrawableRect.centerY(), mDrawableRadius, mFillPaint);
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(mDrawableRect.centerX(), mDrawableRect.centerY(), mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
                if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(mBorderRect.centerX(), mBorderRect.centerY(), mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
                super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
                setup();
            }

            @Override
            public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
                super.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
                setup();
            }

            @Override
            public void setPaddingRelative(int start, int top, int end, int bottom) {
                super.setPaddingRelative(start, top, end, bottom);
                setup();
            }

            public int getBorderColor() {
                return mBorderColor;
            }

            public void setBorderColor(@ColorInt int borderColor) {
                if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
                    return;
                }

                mBorderColor = borderColor;
                mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
                invalidate();
            }

            /**
            * @deprecated Use {@link #setBorderColor(int)} instead
            */
            @Deprecated
            public void setBorderColorResource(@ColorRes int borderColorRes) {
                setBorderColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(borderColorRes));
            }

            /**
            * Return the color drawn behind the circle-shaped drawable.
            *
            * @return The color drawn behind the drawable
            *
            * @deprecated Fill color support is going to be removed in the future
            */
            @Deprecated
            public int getFillColor() {
                return mFillColor;
            }

            /**
            * Set a color to be drawn behind the circle-shaped drawable. Note that
            * this has no effect if the drawable is opaque or no drawable is set.
            *
            * @param fillColor The color to be drawn behind the drawable
            *
            * @deprecated Fill color support is going to be removed in the future
            */
            @Deprecated
            public void setFillColor(@ColorInt int fillColor) {
                if (fillColor == mFillColor) {
                    return;
                }

                mFillColor = fillColor;
                mFillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
                invalidate();
            }

            /**
            * Set a color to be drawn behind the circle-shaped drawable. Note that
            * this has no effect if the drawable is opaque or no drawable is set.
            *
            * @param fillColorRes The color resource to be resolved to a color and
            *                     drawn behind the drawable
            *
            * @deprecated Fill color support is going to be removed in the future
            */
            @Deprecated
            public void setFillColorResource(@ColorRes int fillColorRes) {
                setFillColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(fillColorRes));
            }

            public int getBorderWidth() {
                return mBorderWidth;
            }

            public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
                if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
                    return;
                }

                mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
                setup();
            }

            public boolean isBorderOverlay() {
                return mBorderOverlay;
            }

            public void setBorderOverlay(boolean borderOverlay) {
                if (borderOverlay == mBorderOverlay) {
                    return;
                }

                mBorderOverlay = borderOverlay;
                setup();
            }

            public boolean isDisableCircularTransformation() {
                return mDisableCircularTransformation;
            }

            public void setDisableCircularTransformation(boolean disableCircularTransformation) {
                if (mDisableCircularTransformation == disableCircularTransformation) {
                    return;
                }

                mDisableCircularTransformation = disableCircularTransformation;
                initializeBitmap();
            }

            @Override
            public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
                super.setImageBitmap(bm);
                initializeBitmap();
            }

            @Override
            public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
                super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                initializeBitmap();
            }

            @Override
            public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
                super.setImageResource(resId);
                initializeBitmap();
            }

            @Override
            public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
                super.setImageURI(uri);
                initializeBitmap();
            }

            @Override
            public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
                if (cf == mColorFilter) {
                    return;
                }

                mColorFilter = cf;
                applyColorFilter();
                invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public ColorFilter getColorFilter() {
                return mColorFilter;
            }

            private void applyColorFilter() {
                if (mBitmapPaint != null) {
                    mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
                }
            }

            private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
                if (drawable == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                    return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                }

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;

                    if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
                    } else {
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
                    }

                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                    drawable.draw(canvas);
                    return bitmap;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            private void initializeBitmap() {
                if (mDisableCircularTransformation) {
                    mBitmap = null;
                } else {
                    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
                }
                setup();
            }

            private void setup() {
                if (!mReady) {
                    mSetupPending = true;
                    return;
                }

                if (getWidth() == 0 && getHeight() == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                if (mBitmap == null) {
                    invalidate();
                    return;
                }

                mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

                mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

                mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
                mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

                mFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mFillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mFillPaint.setColor(mFillColor);

                mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
                mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

                mBorderRect.set(calculateBounds());
                mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f);

                mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect);
                if (!mBorderOverlay && mBorderWidth > 0) {
                    mDrawableRect.inset(mBorderWidth - 1.0f, mBorderWidth - 1.0f);
                }
                mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2.0f, mDrawableRect.width() / 2.0f);

                applyColorFilter();
                updateShaderMatrix();
                invalidate();
            }

            private RectF calculateBounds() {
                int availableWidth  = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
                int availableHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

                int sideLength = Math.min(availableWidth, availableHeight);

                float left = getPaddingLeft() + (availableWidth - sideLength) / 2f;
                float top = getPaddingTop() + (availableHeight - sideLength) / 2f;

                return new RectF(left, top, left + sideLength, top + sideLength);
            }

            private void updateShaderMatrix() {
                float scale;
                float dx = 0;
                float dy = 0;

                mShaderMatrix.set(null);

                if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
                    scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
                    dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
                } else {
                    scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
                    dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
                }

                mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
                mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.left, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.top);

                mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
            }

        }
```

> Set the view in your xml

```
            <com.fishpott.fishpott5.Views.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_setprofilepicture_profilepicture_imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/none"
                android:src="@drawable/setprofilepicture_activity_imageholder_default_image"
                app:civ_border_color="@android:color/transparent"
                app:civ_border_width="0dp" />
```

> The reason you see "Views" in my xml call of the CircleImageView is because my CircleImageView.java is in "Views" folder/package.